# Python - How to deal with missing keys while iterating through a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterable

In the following example I iterate through a list of dictionaries and I save the 'age' on a list. However, the second dictionary does not have the key 'age'. In that case I would like the value null to be saved on the list. Any suggetsions on how to achieve this?

```
my_list = [{'age': 0, 'name': 'A'}, {'name': 'B'}, {'age': 2, 'name': 'C'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'D'}, {'age': 4, 'name': 'E'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'F'}]

ages = [li['age'] for li in my_list]
```

Comment: `dict.get(key, default=None)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dict.get(key, default_value)` method, If the key not exist it will return default value. If you don't set default value it will return `None`

```
ages = [li.get('age', 0) for li in my_list]
```